# How can I use jq to create a CSV with multiple headers and detail lines?

Tags: json, csv, jq

I'd like to use jq to output in CSV format, but for multiple headers, followed by multiple details. The solutions that I've already seen on Stack Overflow provide a way to insert a single header, but I haven't found anything for multiple headers.

To give you an idea of what I'm talking about, here is some sample JSON input:

```
[
  {
  "HDR": [1, "abc"],
  "DTL": [ [101,"Descr A"], [102,"Descr B"] ]
  }, {
  "HDR": [2, "def"],
  "DTL": [ [103,"Descr C"], [104,"Descr D"] ]
  }
]
```

Desired output:

```
HDR|1|abc
DTL|101|Descr A
DTL|102|Descr B
HDR|2|def
DTL|103|Descr C
DTL|104|Descr D
```

I don't know if it's possible, but my approach so far has been to try to create a filter to give me the following, since transforming this to what I need would be trivial:

```
["HDR", 1, "abc"]
["DTL", 101, "Descr A"]
["DTL", 102, "Descr B"]
["HDR", 2, "def"]
["DTL", 103, "Descr C"]
["DTL", 104, "Descr D"]
```

To be clear, I know how to do this in any number of scripting languages, but I'm really trying to stick with a single jq filter, if it's at all possible.

Edit: I should clarify that I don't necessarily need to copy the "HDR" and "DTL" keys into the CSV (I can hard-code those), so the sample JSON could look like this, if it makes the problem easier.

```
[
  [
    [1, "abc"],
    [[101,"Descr A"], [102,"Descr B"]]
  ], [
    [2, "def"],
    [[103,"Descr C"], [104,"Descr D"]]
  ]
]
```

Edit: This filter technically answers the question with the second sample data I provided (the last one, that's only arrays and no objects), but I would still appreciate a better answer, if for no other reasons than the header length has to be hard-coded, and putting the HDR into two sets of arrays so that it can be flatten()'d later feels wrong. But I'll leave it here for reference.

`.[] | flatten(1) | [[["HDR"] + .[0:2]]] as $hdr | .[2:] as $dtl | $dtl | map([["DTL"] + .]) as $dtl | $hdr + $dtl | flatten(1) | .[]  | join("|")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for your original input, assuming you chose `|` as the delimiter because none of your fields can contain `|`.

```
jq -r 'map(["HDR"]+.HDR, ["DTL"] + .DTL[])[] | join("|")' data.json
```

- `map` produces multiple array elements per object.
- `.DTL[]` ensures `"DTL"` is prefixed to each sublist
- `[]` flattens the result of the `map`

Comment: That's way better than what I had. I love it. Thanks! For the record, in the actual project I'm working on, it's tab delimited (and tabs will be stripped), but I thought a pipe would make for a better illustration.

Comment: Also, I'd like to thank you for explaining what each of the components of the filter is doing. That's really helpful.

Comment: Ah, replace `join("|")` with `@tsv`, then. That will take care of quoting fields if they themselves might contain tabs.

Comment: Actually, I was mistaken. It's going to be 0x000F-delimited. The app that's reading this output is an old one doesn't escape fields at all, so an uncommon character has to be used as the delimiter. Fortunately jq can do that easily. Thanks again!